# Model Mapper - using custom methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct, modelmapper

A springboot project where I need to construct a DTO for a dashboard view using nominated fields from the parent and nominated fields from the `newest` of each of the children.

The entities are `Plane` which has a OneToMany relationship with Transponder, Maint Check and Transmitter.

Plane

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Plane {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String registration;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "plane")
    private List<Transponder> listTransponder = new ArrayList<>();
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "plane")
    private List<Transmitter> listTransmitter = new ArrayList<>();
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "plane")
    private List<MaintCheck> listMaintCheck = new ArrayList<>();
```

Transponder

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Transponder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private LocalDate dateInserted;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private Plane plane;
}
```

`Maint Check` and `Transmitter` have similar entities with a LocalDate field.

PlaneDTO looks liike

```
@Data
public class PlaneDTO {
private String registration;
private LocalDate maintCheck;      // date of most recent Maint Check
private String transponderCode;    // string of most recent Transponder code 
private Integer channel;           // Intger of most recent Transmitter Freq     
}
```

I have attempted to consruct this PlaneDTO in the service layer, but I am manually doing much of the sorting of the lists of Transponder, Transmitter and Maint Check to get the most recent record from these lists.

```
//DRAFT METHOD CONSTRUCT DTO
@Override
public PlaneSummaryDTO getPlaneSummaryDTOById(Long id) {
  Plane Plane = this.get(id);
  PlaneSummaryDTO PlaneSummaryDTO = new PlaneSummaryDTO();
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    PlaneSummaryDTO = modelMapper.map(get(id), PlaneSummaryDTO.class);
    PlaneSummaryDTO.setTRANSPONDERCode(getNewestTRANSPONDERCode(Plane));
    PlaneSummaryDTO.setLastMaintCheck(getNewestMaintCheckDate(Plane));
    PlaneSummaryDTO.setChannel(getTransmitterCode(Plane));
    PlaneSummaryDTO.setChannelOffset(getTransmitterOffset(Plane));
    return PlaneSummaryDTO;
}

// RETURN NEWEST DATE OF MAINT CHECK BY CATCH DATE
public LocalDate getNewestMaintCheckDate(Plane Plane) {
    List<MaintCheck> listMaintCheck = new ArrayList<>(Plane.getListMaintCheck());
    MaintCheck newest = listMaintCheck.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(MaintCheck::getCatchDate)).get();
    return newest.getCatchDate();
}

// RETURN NEWEST TRANSPONDER CODE FROM Plane BY DATE INSERTED
public String getNewestTransponderCode(Plane Plane) {
    List<Transponder> listTransponder = new ArrayList<>(Plane.getListTransponder());
    Transponder newest = listTransponder.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Transponder::getDateInserted)).get();
    return newest.getCode();
}

// OTHER METHODS TO GET MOST RECENT RECORD
```

**QUESTION** Is there a better way to calculate the most recent record of the child, using model mapper more efficiently (custom method?)

I am open to changing to MapStruct if it better supports getting the most recent child.

Comment: Is the data model itself a good idea? I would expect a place to have one transponder, and if you're interested in transponders it used to have, you'd have to look them up separately. Anyway, "better way" is always a matter of opinion. You can at least give the plane these methods (getLatestTransponder()). Or refactor the similar methods to a single, properly parameterized one.

Comment: Wouldn't storing the most recent transponder against plane break the don't repeat yourself rule? (I would be storing it twice) (yes I am interested in history)

Comment: What I mean is having a different repo for plane and transponder, with one-to-one for current, and a separate access method for previous transponders (eg `TransponderHistoryService#findByPlaneId()`). You'd still save each transponder only once.

Comment: I am interested in testing this concept. Does Plane have two relationships to Transponder table? (OneToMany and a seperate OneToOne?)
The OneToOne stores current Transponder, where as the OneToMany does the List<Transponder> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I briefly used ModelMapper in the past. I would suggest using mapstruct since I personaly find it easier to use. I know your mapping can be done there ;). In Mapstruct your Mapper could look something like this:

```
@MapperConfig(
        componentModel = "spring",
        builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true)
)
public interface PlaneMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "lastMaintCheck", ignore = true)
    PlaneDTO planeToPlaneDTO(Plane plane);

    @AfterMapping
    default void customCodePlaneMapping(Plane source, @MappingTarget PlaneDTO target) {
        target.setLastMaintCheck(source.getListMaintCheck.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Transponder::getDateInserted)).get())
   }
```

Your mapper call would then only be one line:

```
@Service
@RequiuredArgsConstructor
public class someService{

    private final PlaneMapper planeMapper;

    public void someMethod(){
        ....
        PlaneDTO yourMappedPlaneDTO = planeMapper.planeToPlaneDTO(plane);
        ....
    }
```

I did not fill in all values. But i hope the concept is clear.

EDIT:

You would also have to add the dependency of "mapstruct-processor" so that the MapperImpl classes can be gererated.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I follow. But get compile error Parameter 2 of constructor in com..implementation.PlaneServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.mapper.PlaneMapper' that could not be found.

Comment: I had to add bean @Mapper above public interface PlaneMapper - is this right?

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that. The MapperImpl class is a generated class. For this you need to add the dependency for the "mapstruct-processor".

Answer (score 0):

So here's a different approach to the data model. I'll be using Transponder because the others are analog.

The target domain model could look like this:

```
@Data
class Plane {
 Long id;
 String registration;
 Transponder activeTransponder;
}
@Data
class Transponder {
 Long id;
 Integer code; // this is a 4-digit octal number, why String? your call though
 Long planeId; 
 Instant assignStart;
 Instant assignEnd;
}
```

In the database, it would be sufficient to store the id and registration for the plane, because you can determine the current transponder with a proper query on the db entity, eg `where transponder.planeId=id and transponder.assignEnd IS NULL`. You can also store the transponderId of course, but then you'd need to take care to keep the data consistent between the tables.

If you want a history of all transponders - which to me seems like an entirely different use case to me, you can easily retrieve it in a separate service with a query `getTransponderHistoryByPlane(long planeId)` with a query like `from transponders t where t.planeId=$planeId sorted by t.assignStart`.

Again, this does depend on your use cases, and assumes that you usually only need one transponder for a given plane except in special cases, like from a different endpoint.

Anyway, this were my thoughts on the domain model, and you were aiming for your Dto; however, this is then easily mapped with mapstruct like (assuming you do the same for maintCheck and transmitter)

```
@Mapper
interface PlaneDtoMapper {
  @Mapping(target = "transponderCode", source = "transponder.code")
  @Mapping(target = "maintCheck", source = "maintCheck.date")
  @Mapping(target = "channel", source = "transmitter.channel")
  PlaneDTO fromPlane(Plane p);
}
```

You don't need the "registration" mapping because the fields in plane and dto are the same, and the `@Mapping` annotations tell mapstruct which subfields of which fields of plane to use.

Comment: I am still interested in this method but have more questions than is allowed here in commenbts

Comment: what if I want to know which maintenance check the transponder was changed on?